# Android: Unable to pause activity : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered:

Tags: android, illegalargumentexception

I got this error when I pressed the Home button in Android Emulator.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.thesis.dic_ta_han/com.thesis.dic_ta_han.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: android.speech.SpeechRecognizer$Connection@170be3d7 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3219) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3194) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1314) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) Caused by: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: android.speech.SpeechRecognizer$Connection@170be3d7 
    at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1029) 
    at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1816) 
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:551) 
    at android.speech.SpeechRecognizer.destroy(SpeechRecognizer.java:408) 
    at com.thesis.dic_ta_han.MainActivity.onPause(MainActivity.java:83) 
    at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:6101) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1310) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3246) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3219)  
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3194)  
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:151)  
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1314)  
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)  
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)  
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)  
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)  
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)  
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements RecognitionListener {

private TextView returnedText;
private ToggleButton toggleButton;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private SpeechRecognizer speech ;
private Intent recognizerIntent;
private String LOG_TAG = "MainActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    returnedText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    initSpeech();

    toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                     boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
                speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);
            } else {
                progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                speech.stopListening();
            }
        }
    });

}

private void initSpeech(){
    speech = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
    speech.setRecognitionListener(this);
    recognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE,"en");
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, this.getPackageName());
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS, true);
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PREFER_OFFLINE, true);
    recognizerIntent.putExtra("android.speech.extra.DICTATION_MODE", true);
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS, 5000);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (speech != null) {
        speech.destroy();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "destroy");
    }

}

@Override
public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onBeginningOfSpeech");
    progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
    progressBar.setMax(10);
}

@Override
public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onBufferReceived: " + buffer);
}

@Override
public void onEndOfSpeech() {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onEndOfSpeech");
    progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    toggleButton.setChecked(false);
}

@Override
public void onError(int errorCode) {
    String errorMessage = getErrorText(errorCode);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "FAILED " + errorMessage);
    returnedText.setText(errorMessage);
    toggleButton.setChecked(false);
}

@Override
public void onEvent(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onEvent");
}

@Override
public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
    ArrayList<String> matches = partialResults
            .getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
    String text = "";
    for (String result : matches)
        text += result + "\n";

    returnedText.append(text);
}

@Override
public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle arg0) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onReadyForSpeech");
}

@Override
public void onResults(Bundle results) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onResults");
    ArrayList<String> matches = results
            .getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
    String text = "";
    for (String result : matches)
        text += result + "\n";

    returnedText.append(text);
}

@Override
public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onRmsChanged: " + rmsdB);
    progressBar.setProgress((int) rmsdB);
}

public static String getErrorText(int errorCode) {
    String message;
    switch (errorCode) {
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_AUDIO:
            message = "Audio recording error";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_CLIENT:
            message = "Client side error";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSIONS:
            message = "Insufficient permissions";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK:
            message = "Network error";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK_TIMEOUT:
            message = "Network timeout";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NO_MATCH:
            message = "No match";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_RECOGNIZER_BUSY:
            message = "RecognitionService busy";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SERVER:
            message = "error from server";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SPEECH_TIMEOUT:
            message = "No speech input";
            break;
        default:
            message = "Didn't understand, please try again.";
            break;
    }
    return message;
}
}
```

Comment: Try removing super.onPause() from the onPause() method.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but it doesn't work.  The error happened when I'm done recognizing speech and click the home button, But in first initializing the app then clicking the home button no error happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                 boolean isChecked) {


        initSpeech();
        if (isChecked) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
            speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);
        } else {
            progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            speech.stopListening();
        }
    }
});
```

call initSpeech inside the onCheckedChange().Otherwise sometime the speechReconginzer object may be destroyed.

This may help you

Try to destroy the speech object onError() endOfSpeech() and onResults() if Reconginzer Busy Error occur

Comment: Thanks for your comment it works. One more thing. if the user on the toggle button the speech recognizer will initialize when user accidentally or try to press home button that error happen again how to prevent that? or how to stop or destroy the recognizer upon clicking home button? Thank You

Comment: check whether speech objct is null or not befor starListening and stopListening. And also check wheter it is the same problem as you have mentioned above

Comment: yes sir , same error as i mentioned above. This time error happen when the toggle button is on then when i click home button that error happened.. but when the toggle button is off then click home button it works well.

Comment: use if (isChecked && speech!=null){ condition } This may help you to solve your problem