# Android TV SearchFragment Error SpeechRecognizer

Tags: android, speech-recognition

Actually I am new to Leanback and I am working in the search part and implement SearchFragment. I am facing this issue on error log message (when run on device, but working on android virtual device):

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: android.speech.SpeechRecognizer$Connection@f545b3e
```

If any one knows please update. Thank you.

Comment: Could it be related to a missing recognition provider? https://stackoverflow.com/q/37856993/1256219

Comment: @Tomero: I also an error same as you.
Have you been resolve problem?

Comment: I dont get any solution for this, Im still waiting :'(

Comment: I also crash at:  **super.onPause(); => mSpeechRecognizer.destroy();**

Comment: Also have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46701736/1759443

Comment: Yes. But i'm using SearchSupportFragment and SpeechRecognizer automatically initialized and starts at first time created (default). Have you used by SearchSupportFragment ?

Comment: @MrSiro Do you find any solution?

Comment: I am also looking for the same error. can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

It may not be relevant anymore, but I myself did something like:

```
override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        try {
            if (!Utils.isATV(requireContext())) {
                val mSpeechRecognizerField: Field = SearchSupportFragment::class.java.getDeclaredField("mSpeechRecognizer")
                mSpeechRecognizerField.isAccessible = true
                mSpeechRecognizerField.set(this, null)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("", "Method not found")
        }

    }
```

Conditions and checks can be done at your discretion. I have voice search on Google's AndroidTV (leanback), but on other devices it is turned off.

You can check for the presence of the service itself in the system.